# Bootstrap - Div is shown below navbar, instead of right of navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to setup a navbar which is always at the very left of the screen, and a main container which is always right of the navbar. Currently it is always below the navbar. The main container (titled with dashboard) should always be right of the navbar, even if the screen is too small. In the main container there is currently only one table shown. The width of this table should be fluid.

Here are my jsfiddle resources:

[Source](http://jsfiddle.net/yhPdA/)

[Result](http://jsfiddle.net/yhPdA/embedded/result/)

It would be great if I could set the width when the main body is not shrinking anymore, something like a min-width for the main container.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: See my answer below, Hope it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sidebar must be inside the container to get it and the "dashboard" side by side.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
            <!--Sidebar content-->
        </div>
        <div class="span8">
            <!--Dashboard content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To prevent resizing under certain screen sizes, just get a custom Bootstrap [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html), unchecking that sizes you don't want to support.

Comment: Thats a good step in the right direction :) Thanks! I updated the jsfiddle. But the dashboard still moves under the navbar when the screen is resized / shrinked -> http://jsfiddle.net/yhPdA/1/embedded/result/. Do you really think this can be solved with a custom bootstrap version?

Comment: Custom Bootstrap will prevent resizing below certain sizes. Give it a try an if it doesn't fit your requirements we can search a solution.

Comment: In your fiddle <div class="row-fluid"> is missing! It changes behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, that solved the issue. When unchecking the responsive features it stops putting the dashboard content under the sidebar content.